# Select Intersecting and flanking regions in MySQL query

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am using a mysql database with a table with genomic islands in the format:

```
+----+-------+----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+
| id | chrom | start    | end      | line_string                                   |
+----+-------+----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+
|  1 |     1 | 36568608 | 36569851 |                 ??    ?o?A      ??   ?p?A       |
|  2 |     1 | 82313020 | 82313491 |                 ??   ????A      ??   L??A         |
+----+-------+----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

The linestring is in the format: `GeomFromText('Linestring(chrom start, chrom end)')`
the numbers for "start" and "end" refer to basepair positions

I am currently selecting Island vs. non-Island regions in my python script using:

```
SELECT 'Island' as Island FROM islands 
WHERE MBRIntersects(GeomFromText('Linestring(%d %d, %d %d)'), line_string) 
UNION ALL SELECT 'non-Island' LIMIT 1 % (Chr, Start, Chr, End)
```

However, I would like to amend this query to also give island shores and shelfs defined as:

Island shore - 2,000 basepairs from Island

Island shelf - 2,000 to 4,000 basepairs from Island

Comment: For those of us not in genomics, your lingo is a puzzling mixture of geometry and oceanography. Can you help us understand how you'd get a `shore` or a `shelf` from an ordinary `line_string` value?

Comment: @OllieJones: The terms Island, shore and shelf are just terms that biologist use for CpG dense regions and their surroundings. They're irrelevant to the actual question. I use the geometric terms as a faster way to search for intersecting genomic regions. Imagine regions of DNA as strings with the x-axis as the chromosome number and y axis the location on the chromosome. In this way I can easily check for intersecting genomic coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using:

```
SELECT 'Island' as Island FROM methylation.islands FORCE INDEX (locations)
            WHERE MBRIntersects(GeomFromText('Linestring(%d %d, %d %d)'), line_string) 
        UNION ALL SELECT 'Shore' FROM methylation.islands FORCE INDEX (locations) 
            WHERE MBRIntersects(GeomFromText('Linestring(%d %d, %d %d)'), line_string)
        UNION ALL SELECT 'Shelf' FROM methylation.islands FORCE INDEX (locations) 
            WHERE MBRIntersects(GeomFromText('Linestring(%d %d, %d %d)'), line_string)
        UNION ALL SELECT 'Other' LIMIT 1 
% (Chr, Start, Chr, End, Chr, Start-2000, Chr, End+2000, Chr, Start-4000, Chr, End+4000)
```

In this way anything that is an "Island" is listed as such, next if it's +/- 2,000 basepairs from an island it gets listed as a "shore", next if it's +/- 4,000 basepairs it's listed as a "shelf". Lastly everything else is considered "Other". By using a `LIMIT 1` only the first found term is returned.